# JavaScript: innerHtml to change 'display' from '1' to '0' no errors on console

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, domcontentloaded

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type= "text/javascript" src= "calc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Calculate away </h2>
    <div id='display'>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS File**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', turnOn)
function turnOn ()
{
    document.getElementById('display').innerHtml = "`<p>0</p>`";
}
```

Comment: Are the people giving answers correctly guessing the question you didn't ask?

Comment: No error then what is the question there?

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is the correct name.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', turnOn)

function turnOn () {
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "<p>0</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `document.getElementById('display').innerHtml` to `document.getElementById('display').innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector` just to replace the text of the `p` tag .

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', turnOn)

function turnOn() {
  var getPElement = document.querySelector("#display p")
  getPElement.innerHTML = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1> Calculate away </h2>
  <div id='display'>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
```